# Doctrine 2 Order By w/ Functions

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to do this in Symfony2 with Doctrine2 v. 2.1.7:

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery(
            "SELECT a
            FROM ".$repo." a
            WHERE a.type_id = :typeid
              AND a.scenario = :scen
              AND a.contact_id = :cid
              AND a.row_type LIKE :rwtp
            ORDER BY SUBSTRING(a.row_type, 4, 1)  "
        )->setParameters(
            array(
                'typeid'    =>$sesData['type_id'],
                'scen'      =>$sesData['scenario'],
                'cid'       =>$sesData['contact_id'],
                'rwtp'      =>'%.'.$whereVal.'%'
            )
        );

$customValues =  $query->getResult();
```

Doctrine 2 fails on the ORDER BY clause because it doesn't like anything in there except a column name and a sort direction it appears.

I've looked at the documentation for using a native query, but that won't work because this query is used to pull data from several tables (it sits inside a global method we use) so I can't do that mapping stuff because beyond the where clause above, the rest of the column names are different from table to table.

I think that in order to pull this off, I'm going to need a truly native query that does the mapping (hydration?) automatically like all the other DQL queries that are not native. But that part has me stymied.

What can I try to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating another column where you already store the result of `SUBSTRING(a.row_type, 4, 1)` e. g. on insert, map that column and order by that? It would be way more efficient anyhow compared to computing the substring on every query for every row.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. As you say, that would work very well and would be more efficient. In my specific situation however, it becomes more difficult than it is worth for reasons not mentioned in the original post. I was kind of hoping for a database sorting approach.

Answer (score 0):

It will be less efficient but have you considered the possibility of sorting the results yourself using one of the php sort functions after getting them back from the database? If your result sets are not very large this may be a sensible approach.

Comment: Yes, I am actually doing that in the code at present to make it work, but it makes my stomach hurt. I was hoping I might perform the ORDER BY sort (when needed) in the database. If it simply isn't possible w/ Doctrine 2, I'll continue letting PHP sort the result set for me and hope that functionality gets added in a future Doctrine 2 release.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a, SUBSTRING(a.row_type, 4, 1) AS row_type
        FROM ".$repo." a
        WHERE a.type_id = :typeid
          AND a.scenario = :scen
          AND a.contact_id = :cid
          AND a.row_type LIKE :rwtp
        ORDER BY row_type
```